# IBM MQGET and MQPUT

Tags: ibm-mq

I am making a small program to put and get messages from queues. I have implemented a client version easily with no errors.

However when i attempt to make a server version i get a number of errors complaining about the MQ Calls i am using:

Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _MQCLOSE referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall CImbMq::Disconnect(void)" (?Disconnect@CImbMq@@UAE_NXZ)

i have

```
#include <cmqc.h>
#include <cmqxc.h>
```

included and have included the MQSERIES_SRV_LIBRARIES located in my IBM/Tools/Lib64 folder

Any idea's why i continue to get these errors ?

Thanks

Comment: Is it throwing similar errors for other MQI calls like MQOPEN, MQGET, MQPUT et all. How are you making the server version?  Are you linking with libmqm or libmqm_r and not with libmqic?  Is the code same for both client and server versions?  ie, do they use a svrconn channel to connect to the qmgr?

Comment: I found where the server libs should of been held and they arnt , all in all , didnt have the server lib files to hand.

Comment: Only a WMQ server installation can supply these files for you.  Install MQ server and compile the application in bindings mode.

Answer (score 1):

That linking error is telling you that it cannot resolve the MQ calls. If you have already successfully linked a client version of the application, that tells me that you do not have MQ server installation, and so the libraries for linking a server (or local bindings) version of your application, are not installed on your machine.